# React - passing the return of a function as prop

Tags: javascript, react.js

The code below works as intended but I'm not sure the way I'm passing it to a component is correct. Also, I don't think the way I wrote this function is recommended. It's not a pure function and probably should be split into two functions where one needs the output of the other.

'books' and 'authors' are 'state' objects in this functional component. The author list is dynamic based on the users choices (author list checkboxes). As I said, it works fine but it's probably not written the way it should:

```
const selectedBooks = (books, authors) => {
    // get the list of the currently selected authors and save it in a list.
    const authorList = authors.filter(author => author.active).map(item => item.name);
    // filter the list of books for the currently selected authors
    const bookList =  books.filter(book => authorList.includes(book.source.name));
    return bookList;
}
```

And then it's passed:

```
<BookList books={selectedBooks(books, authors)} />
```

EDIT based on the comment:
That's what I thought. So would I do the following:

```
const selectedBooks = (books, authors) => {
        // get the list of the currently selected authors and save it in a list.
        const authorList = authors.filter(author => author.active).map(item => item.name);
        // filter the list of books for the currently selected authors
        const bookList =  books.filter(book => authorList.includes(book.source.name));
        return bookList;
    }

const booksToPass = selectedBooks(books, authors);

...

<BookList books={booksToPass} />
```

Comment: In isolation it appears to be a perfectly valid utility function, and I don't disagree with its usage to compute *a* prop value. I may only suggest it doesn't compute it in-line in the props. If it's just the one component and usage perhaps it's unnecessary, but maybe you have more uses for it.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the modification. Have I understood you correctly? Thanks

Comment: Yup, precisely. I believe for readability the JSX should be as tight and concise as possible.

Comment: I'd rather remove the `map()` and use `some()` instead of `includes()`. Saves a function call with another temporary array so might be more performant

Comment: @SonNguyen Ok, took me a minute to wrap my head around that comment, but basically `bookList = books.filter(book => authorList.some(({ name }) => name === book.source.name);`, is this correct? These are all linear \$O(n)\$ operations, i.e. traversing the array to map, filter, or match a criteria; removing a single map just cuts out a constant time factor. I like the suggestion, but don't think it would be more, or less, performant, and likely is more a readability issue, what a dev is more familiar with, though both require about the same level-of-knowledge of array functions to understand.

Comment: @SonNguyen Also, could you clarify your map() comment? Would you replace it with forEach? I chose map() because, unlike forEach, it returns a new object, which is needed here. Am I correct?

Comment: Wasteland, I believe they meant just dropping the mapping in computing the author list, i.e. `const authorList = authors.filter(author => author.active);` then changing the second book list computation to something similar to my previous comment. `authorList` is an array of author objects, thus the object destructuring of `name` property in the array::some callback.